# Finding a number from a list that has the most prime factors

Tags: python

I have given a list of numbers and the problem is to find the one which has the most number of distinct prime factors. I have tried this code to calculate prime numbers less than a given number:

```
number=int(input())
def is_prime(n):
    if n<=1:
        return False
    
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n%i==0:
           return False
    return True


primes=[]
count=0
for x in range(2,number):
    if is_prime(x)==True:
        count+=1
        primes.append(x)

print(primes)
print(count)
```

but I do not know how can I continue to determine desired number.

Comment: so how many prime factors does 20 has? 2 or 3?

Comment: Woah, is there a time limit? You might want to look into precalculating aan array of prime numbers using an efficient method (e.g. Sieve of Eratosthenes) and then comparing with that.

Comment: You should have the list of numbers. then you have to calculate the number of primes each number in the list have. finally get the one with the maximum number of primes

Comment: Do you have a list of arbitrary numbers, from which you need to determine the one with the most prime factors, or do have lists of the specific form [1,n]? Your wording suggests the former but your code suggests the latter. Those are two very different questions. For the second question, think of it as the problem of how to construct a number with many prime factors.

Comment: @AvenDesta It must be 2.(2 and 5). but I am surprised where did you bring 20? :D

Comment: @JHBonarius No, there is not any time limit. I am wondering why you are asking this

Comment: @AvenDesta & John Coleman I want to give a list of ten numbers from user as input and print the one with the biggest number of prime factors as output

Comment: @Kianoosh.kargar 20 = 2x2x5, it is divisible by 3 prime factors, but only 2 distinct prime factors. The word "distinct" was not present in your question, hence Aven Desta asked for needed clarification. Both types of counting are used in number theory, see the Wikipedia article on the [Prime omega function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function).

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of distinct prime factors of `n`, (known as [omega(n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function)), you can exploit three ideas:

1. Every number is either prime or has a prime divisor which is less than or equal to its square root
2. Every prime factor other than 2 is odd
3. Once you find such a prime divisor, you can reduce the target number by as many factors of that divisor as possible, hence constantly reducing the size of the problem.

One implementation of these ideas:

```
def omega(n):
    """counts the number of distinct prime factors of n"""
    if n < 2:
        return 0
    else:
        count = 0
        if n % 2 == 0:
            count += 1
            while n % 2 == 0:
                n //= 2
        d = 3
        while d*d <= n:
            if n % d == 0:
                count += 1
                while n % d == 0:
                    n //= d
            d += 2
        if n > 1:
            count += 1
    return count
```

To find which number in a given list has the highest number of distinct prime factors, you can use the fact that the built-in python function `max` has an optional `key` parameter:

```
def max_primes(nums):
    return max(nums,key = omega)
```

For instance,

```
>>> max_primes([1,2,42,200,210,211,360])
210
```

Note that ties are possible and even likely. There typically won't exist a single number in a given list which has more prime factors than all of the other numbers. For example,

```
>>> max_primes(range(101))
30
>>> omega(30)
3
>>> [n for n in range(101) if omega(n) == 3]
[30, 42, 60, 66, 70, 78, 84, 90]
```

You could modify the `max_primes` function to return the list of all numbers in the list which have the maximal number of primes. For that you can create a dictionary whose keys are the given numbers and whose values are the prime counts. Apply `max` to the values and then use a list comprehension to extract the corresponding keys.